# angularjs directive requires A or B

Tags: angularjs

With AngularJS directive, if directive `c` has parent tag `a`,
I do like this

```
require: '^a'
```

However, if `c` requires parent tag `a` or `b`
I tried this with ctrls in link function, but no luck.

```
require: ['?a', '?b']
```

I tried this but with error

```
require: '?(a|b)'
```

What is the syntax when a directive requires `a` or `b`?

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to use

```
require: ['?^a', '?^b']
```

to grab both optional controllers from some parent. This will give you back an array of the controllers or null if they don't exist. You will need to check for yourself whether one controller has been provided or not.

Depending on why you need this, it may be nicer to give both of your parent directives the same controller name

```
name: 'myParent'
```

and then require it non-optionally with

```
require: '^myParent'
```

in the child.

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to do it in the `require` property, based on the Angular source code.  Angular only wants one of two options:

1. String containing a combination of (^/?/?^/empty) flag and the name of one directive.
2. Array of strings that match the criteria in option number one.

So the fanciest you could get would be a mix of some required parent controllers and some optional parent controllers.

```
//AngularJS 1.2

function getControllers(require, $element) {
    var value, retrievalMethod = 'data', optional = false;
    if (isString(require)) {
        while((value = require.charAt(0)) == '^' || value == '?') {
            require = require.substr(1);
            if (value == '^') {
                retrievalMethod = 'inheritedData';
            }
            optional = optional || value == '?';
        }

        value = $element[retrievalMethod]('$' + require + 'Controller');

        ...

        if (!value && !optional) {
            throw $compileMinErr('ctreq',
                "Controller '{0}', required by directive '{1}', can't be found!",
                require, directiveName);
        }
        return value;
    } else if (isArray(require)) {
        value = [];
        forEach(require, function(require) {
            value.push(getControllers(require, $element));
        });
    }
    return value;
}
```